# React does not charge images in the display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem in my small project, i do not show me image on display

cardData.js

```
async fetchData(){

   await axios.get(`${this.urlApi}${this.props.url}${this.apiKey}`).then(d=>this.setState({data:d.data}))

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }


  render() {
  const data=this.state.data.results;
    if(data)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>        
          <div >
          <Carousel slidesToShow={5}  dragging={true} slidesToScroll={3} cellSpacing={5}>
            {data.map(d=><Card key={d.id} title={d.title} img={d.poster_path} data={d}/>)}
          </Carousel>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
      return<div className="loader" />  
  }
}
```

screen of problem: [image]

for full source code : [github repo](https://github.com/aymen94/reactflix)

Comment: Most likely, the image URLs stored in `d.poster_path` are broken. You should make sure they are valid. You could, for example, check them with a `console.log` statement

Comment: Do you really need the `async`, `await`? Since you are using `then` as promised based in order to get the response maybe you don't have to fetch asynchronously.  Also, can you `console.log` the request's output just to check whether you get the correct response?

Comment: @PatrickHund All images work

Comment: @HemersonCarlin The request's  is correct, but i refresh the website 2 or 3 times until it  work

Comment: what's that `Carousel` component you are using? Did you write it yourself, or is it a library? If so, which one?

Comment: check console for invalid images loaded... you are using `this.imageUrl+this.props.img` as src of the image... maybe a missing "/" between them? `console.log` those values to see what they have

Comment: @PatrickHund And a library I've edited, but this is not the problem if you { return<div className="loader" />  }
it works

Comment: HemersonCarlin ist right, if you use async / await, you simply write it like this: `const d = await  axios.get(`${this.urlApi}${this.props.url}${this.apiKey}`); this.setState({data:d.data});`

Comment: try fixing that and see if it works

Comment: @PatrickHund i tried , not work :(